# Can Dell dock wd19tb with dell xps 13 drive two 4k 60hz and 1 wqhd 60hz monitor?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, dell-xps, docking-station

I have a Dell laptop, connected to Dell's WT19TB dock. I currently run two 4k 60hz monitors via the dock and they run fine. I'd like to add a third monitor, a BenQ WQHD (2560x1440) 60hz monitor. Right now, when I open display settings in Windows, the new monitor shows up, but it is greyed out.

[image]

I read online that these monitors may just need more bandwidth than either the computer or the dock can provide. Is this the case?

I'm not a gamer and I don't watch high fidelity videos on this setup (this is basically a work computer). Can I reduce the resolution to something lower to get the third monitor to work?

Comment: The graphics card is likely to be the limiting factor and no, changing resolutions won't help.

Comment: As ChanganAuto said - the limiting factor is the Graphic Card. Most likely the Graphic Card can only handle 3 display. You may be able to do this by closing the laptop (to turn off / disable the Laptop screen) - and then just use the 3 external screens and see if that works.

Comment: That's interesting. Closing the laptop did make the third monitor work. However, the resolution was only 567x1440 and the screen was very jittery.